# Problems with Spring Roo DBRE generated Project with GWT

Tags: java, spring, gwt, spring-roo

I generate a roo project using this script:

The expenses sample with gwt works and my database reverse engineering also works with web mvc.
But with web gwt it throws classNotFound exceptions for each Locator since they are not generated and gwt can't use the default for no known reason.

One thing I found is that gwt only supports jpaActiveRecord which I think I am using anyway.

roo script:

```
project --topLevelPackage con --projectName con --java 6 --packaging WAR
persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database MSSQL --databaseName conDB --userName user --password 123 --hostName localhost
osgi start --url file://.../jtds-1.2.5.jar
database reverse engineer --schema dbo --package ~.domain --testAutomatically --enableViews 
web gwt setup
web gwt all --proxyPackage ~.client.proxy --requestPackage ~.client.request
```

sample error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sop.connect.server.locator.PersonsLocator
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:352)
[ERROR]     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:337)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
[ERROR]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.LocatorServiceLayer.resolveLocator(LocatorServiceLayer.java:122)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you remove the assignment versionField = "" from the @RooJpaActiveRecord annotation of a domain object, then Locator class will be generated in the same folder as the domain object and another necessary modifications in the ITD files will be done.